# Approaches for unit testing DB components

Tags: unit-testing

I have a component that provides a CRUD interface to store and manage data internally in a database. For unit testing this component, I have several options:

1. Test each method individually using a mock DB client and check whether the correct methods were called with the correct arguments,
2. Test each method individually using a functional DB client and check whether the internal state of the DB is as expected,
3. Test methods together, e.g.,

   ```
   put("a", "1");
   result = get("a");
   assert_equals("1", result);
   ```

I personally tend to use method 3 because 1 and 2 are very fragile towards changes to the underlying data management. But what are the pros and cons of each method? Which method is usually used for such code?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is a *unit test*, and is what you should be using when you want to test the **business logic** of your application in isolation. It doesn't rely on the database being in any particular state, and executes much faster than the other two options.

Method 2 is *not* a unit test, but rather an *integration test*. It is useful when you want to test the authenticity of **the actual data** being sent to and from your database. It's also useful for testing data transmission speeds and for issues with things like database locks.

Method 3 is also an *integration test*, and is not considered reliable for testing individual database calls, as it does not verify that the data that was inserted was inserted by the test itself; `put()` could have failed, and the `get()` could have retrieved data that was already stored in the database. However, it *can* be useful for testing things that *must* happen in conjunction. For example, subtracting a payment from one account at the same time as adding it to another. Typically these would both be combined in a `try / catch` statement.

While there is nothing stopping you from using all three methods, method 1 will give you the most bang for your buck, as the emphasis should always be placed on unit testing over integration testing.

Comment: For testing, you'd normally use a temporary database that is in a *known state* before the test, so `get` should return nothing if `put` failed, right?